# Absolute positioning without units "px"

Tags: css

On web.archive.org/web/20190725155929/http://binditall.com/BowitAll.html, elements are positioned absolutely and do not have "px" specified. But everything works.
I restored this site from the web archive, but on my site binditall.com/BowitAll.html the browser swears that the units for "left, right, top, bottom" are not specified
To make my site work like a sample without adding "px"?

Comment: Hi Anton, please include the minimum reproducible code to get your question best answered; otherwise we are unable to guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

```
element.style {
position: absolute;
left: 197;
top: 1517;
width: 558;
height: 183;}
```

This css code not working in my restored site, but working in web.archive site

Comment: your css selector is not correct, it will target `<element class="style"></element>` only, not the actual element you want, the reason devtools shows that is because it is on the style attribute, so try using that